# CSS Webfont not rendering missing character

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using the "Quicksand" font for a web project (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Quicksand) and I've a problem : the ² character doesn't exist for that font. I thought that it would be rendered in other fonts (written after Quicksand in the font-family property), but it is not. When I write ², the only thing rendered is a white space.

Is there a way to render not supported characters by other fonts ?

Here's the CSS used :

```
font-family: "Quicksand", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: wrap that character in a span and apply other font family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Quicksand font: for the Unicode code position U+00B2, SUPERSCRIPT TWO, it has an empty glyph. It is 396 units wide, so it is wider than a normal SPACE (300 units) in the font. Another character with a similar problem is U+201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK “‚”, which has an empty glyph 230 units wide.

In principle, you could circumvent the bug by using `unicode-range` in a `@font-face` rule to specify that a particular character be taken from a different font. However, browser support is still too limited (and the approach would require that you host the font files instead of using them from the Google server).

Another possibility would be to edit the font. This requires a font editor and a permission from the copyright holder (and your hosting the font files of course).

A third option is to wrap each occurrence of “²” in a `span` element with a class and setting `font-family` on them suitably. Beware that this means mixing glyphs from different fonts, which should be avoided in good typography.

Finally, consider using a different font. There are several questions about rendering problems with the Quicksand font at SO.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. Finally my only option was to change font for input/select/textarea elements...